# Webpack dev server - exporting .CSS file on change

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm building .SASS into one .CSS file using webpack, but it only exports the file when I "webpack" in the terminal. When I run "webpack-dev-server" it sees the changes but doesn't generate/change the output .CSS file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',  // this exports the final .js file
        publicPath: '/public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
            },

           {
                test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass') // this loads SASS
            }

        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./bundle.css") //this exports the CSS file
    ],

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss'],
        root: [path.join(__dirname, './src')]
    }
};
```

It works completely fine with just "webpack" but I wonder how to make it generate the file using the server, so that I don't have to type in the terminal every time I make a change to the styles.

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` generates files and serves from memory, not from file system.

Comment: You need to add `style-loader` to ExtractTextPlugin: `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')`

Comment: Hmm, it renders the file but doesn't put it in the directory. Here's a screenshot of the terminal: http://i.imgur.com/OJGrpKY.png

Comment: It is ok since `webpack-dev-server` serves it from memory.

Comment: I realised how stupid my last question sounded. It all works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally fine. `webpack-dev-server` does not write to disk. It serves from memory only. This is why terminal shows:

`Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from /Users/dd/Desktop/apps/webpack-starter/dist`